# Nested UIStackViews in UIScrollView Lag

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uiscrollview, uistackview

I have a view that has scrollview as a parent. Inside Scrollview, there is a parent stackview nested to many child stack views (all vertical). View is a bit bulky and has many elements. Based on certain characteristics, some of the subviews inside particular stack view are set to hide/unhide.

Problem is when I try to push this view controller, it takes 3-5 second delay to load. I am sure there are not any other task blocking except loading UI components. Can anyone help fix this lag?
Or will I have to programmatically add arranged subviews to stack views ?

The attached image is my view hierarchy
[View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9d3U.png)

Comment: Scroll Views will lag, try using UITableView or UICollectionView to optimise performance and remove lag.

Comment: You'll need to provide more detail. Assuming the image you show is your layout in Storyboard... Are you "filling" the stack views in `viewDidLoad()`? or just setting `.isHidden` where needed? If you simply push to that view controller (take out all of the adding of subviews from `viewDidLoad()`, do you still see the lag? If not, then you need to evaluate what all you are doing to load / add subviews.

Comment: @DonMag in didLoad, I just initialize the components with viewModel. This initialization will hide elements from stack views that do no belong to current state. That's it. I tried moving that initialization functions to viewDidAppear() and pushing view controller was fast but as soon as view is shown, there is a lag that will freeze the view for same couple of seconds.

Comment: *"... I just initialize the components with viewModel. This initialization will hide elements from stack views that do no belong to current state. That's it..."* OK - if you're only setting `.isHidden` on UI elements that need to be hidden, you need to evaluate how you are determining that. I just put this together as a test: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwQsX.png ... each time I tap the button at the top, I loop through all 52 arranged subviews and randomly set the `.isHidden` property. On an iPhone 7 (device), it takes an average of about `0.003` seconds to update the screen.

Comment: @DonMag even after commenting codes that changes the visibility of elements, lag is still there. What can be the possible cause ? And what solution do you recommend. Is it because I have used excessive number of stackViews ?

Comment: @NikeshShakya - You need to investigate what's causing the delay. Where / when are you getting your "viewModel" that determines which views should be hidden? Are you only setting `.isHidden` properties? Or are you also setting other properties of the subviews? Here is the example I put together for you to test... maybe you'll see something from that: https://github.com/DonMag/LotsOfStacks ... if that doesn't help, think about putting together a [mre] so we can see exactly what you are doing.